# FindViewById not detecting id

Tags: android, layout, findviewbyid

I'm having a strange issue in my Android Application. I'm not new in this world and i've never experienced a problem like this. In my xml i define some views. I can reference all of them from java but one. That one is this:  android:id="@+id/mytextview".

I leave the whole code below.

Thanks in advance!

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Cover"
    android:background="#FFC125" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/usersite_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hola"/>

        <View 
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_below="@+id/usersite_title"/>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="6"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line1"
            android:id="@+id/layout1">

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/userlogo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/imageborders" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center">

                <TextView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Actualmente tienes"/>

                <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/mytextview"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"/>

                <TextView 
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="puntos acumulados"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View 
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"/>

        <TextView 
           android:id="@+id/ultimospedidos"
           android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/line2"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="Mis últimos pedidos"/>  

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ultimospedidos"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <View 
            android:id="@+id/line3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView1"/>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/hacerpedido"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hacer pedido"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/CustomButton"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line3"
            android:src="@drawable/repartidor" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what exactly the problem in your controller class. is this ? `can not be resolved`.

Comment: Have you tried Project->Clean? Or try deleting R.java so that Eclipse rebuilds it.

Comment: Exactly. Can not be resolved.

Comment: @Aldridge1991 Post the code with `FindViewById` that can't be resolved.

Comment: Now R is not being detected. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: @Aldridge1991 Could you please post your Java activity code?

Comment: R.java won't build if you have a compile error in one of your xml resources.

Comment: Check your xml resources, that's the cause of the problem.Then Clean / Build

Comment: That was the fault. I had named a XML file with capital letters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing red cross mark on res folder? If so, Eclipse is unable to generate the R.java file, so first fix that error and then clean the project. Hope it  solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
go to gen folder in package delete the content of R.java file 
which said /* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
But still delete (content not file)them all and do project ->clean!
and delete  import android.R if it imported accidentally.
```

Comment: While this may be the right answer you should really consider formatting it to improve the readability.